# Building a time series model

Tags: python, time, model, time-series

[image]

I am working on building a time series model, but the dataset I have only has date features for the year; the month and date are not available. What would be a suitable model to use and is it even possible? The dataset is an Excel file from different years I have merged into a single sheet with records for each year arranged in alphabetical order.

Comment: Can you provide an example of your data? And maybe what is your goal to accomplish with this data?

Comment: Sure @MarkusSchmidgall just shared a screenshot of the data for the year 2017

Comment: Looks like the stack has met its match...over and out,